# SICP 1.2.4 typo in fast-exp?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am going through SICP and I am not sure if this is a mistake in the book or maybe I missed something.

For calculating `fast-exp` authors gave the following rules:

> b^n = (b^(b/2))^2    if n is even
>
> b^n = b * b^(n - 1)  if n is odd

However when they present the implementation for the even `n` we have:

```
((even? n) (square (fast-expt b (/ n 2))))
```

which in my opinion is correct.

I believe

`b^n = (b^(b/2))^2    if n is even`

should be changed to

`b^n = (b^(n/2))^2    if n is even`.

It is hard for me to believe that in so old book there is such mistake. I also tried to find any discussion about this issue on the web but failed. Not sure what is going on here. Thanks in advance.

[link to the mentioned chapter](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%25_sec_1.2.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's a typo - the formula should be `(b^(n/2))^2` if `n` is even. But it has been corrected in the [errata](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/errata.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!