# Scheme: Proabably a typo in SICP. 1.3.2. Am I right?

Tags: scheme, sicp

In SICP, (1.3.2. page: 62), there is a solution for finding `pi-sum` using lambda.  The solution is:

```
(define (pi-sum a b)
  (sum (lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 2))))
       a
       (lambda (x) (+ x 4))
       b))
```

However, I feel there should be a bracket enclosing `((lambda (x) (+ x 4) b)`. The program as such produces an error saying `sum` is expecting a `number` but getting a `procedure`.

Modifying the above code is giving no error.

```
(define (pi-sum a b)
  (sum ((lambda (x) (/ 1.0 (* x (+ x 2))))
       a)
       ((lambda (x) (+ x 4))
       b)))
```

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. I assume the book cannot be wrong.

Comment: In sicp you won't ever see a typo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604094/sicp-1-2-4-typo-in-fast-exp

Comment: in sicp there is no typo. All are corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pi-sum` procedure in the book is making use of the higher-order procedure `sum`, defined earlier in 1.3.1. The `sum` procedure takes `a` and `b` as arguments which describe the bounds of the summation, and it takes `term` and `next` as arguments which describe how to create a term from `a`, and how to get the next `a` from the current `a`. Both `term` and `next` need to be *procedures*. Here is the definition of `sum` from the book:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a)
         (sum term (next a) next b))))
```

If you add parentheses in the definition of `pi-sum`, you should get an exception because `sum` requires four arguments, but now only two are passed. I am not sure why you are getting an error like "*`sum` is expecting a `number` but getting a `procedure`*", but I suspect that you have a different definition for `sum` than the one intended by the book.

Comment: Sorry.  It's my mistake.  Instead of understanding the `sum` procedure, I defined my own sum procedure `(define sum +)`. Thanks.